# How to compare two posts including their meta fields on a scalable base?

Tags: posts, post-meta, comparison

I have set up a wordpress in a way that posts can be cloned and be altered by a different author. whenever this is the case, i want the administrator to be notified via an additional tab in the edit.php screen like *Changes(5)* where only posts are listed whose content and meta fields differ from those of their originals.

to achive this i thought of writing some sort of hash whenever a post is saved to then only compare hashes.

is there a better way of doing this?